# SSRS 2005 grouping issue: Duplicates appear beneath a lower group level when exported to Excel

Tags: reporting-services, duplicates, grouping, rows

I have an SSRS 2005 report that appears normal in SSRS; however, a duplicate set of rows is added below the second row grouping when exported to Excel 2007.

I am not all that familiar with the more advanced reporting techniques in SSRS 2005, and am struggling to find the right answer. Is there any way to remove this?

[image: Excel screenshot]

(Original image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCchD.jpg)

Comment: Those aren't duplicates - they're totals for all Offices for a given Name. Can a given Name have more than one Office?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though your report matrix is grouped by Year, Staff Category, Name and Office. If there is never more than one Office per Name, then the solution is:

- remove the grouping on Office (this should also remove the Office column);
- insert a new column to the right of the Name column, with the new column heading set to Office and the corresponding row value expression set to `=Fields!Office.Value`. (Don't drag and drop the column from the dataset, or you may inadvertently add a grouping on Office to the matrix.)

Comment: Mark, apologies for the slow response. That worked perfectly and the report has completed our deployment process.